# Logstash input event size calculation

Tags: logstash, size, monitoring, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I want to monitor Logstash event size per minute from a particular event source.
I am collecting events from multiple application and want to track how much data each application is sending to Logstash in bytes.

I am able to count number of events per application but now stuck with size/volume metric.
Is there any way we can achieve this in Logstash